# I would like the given prices to make a ZONE

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
1834.14
1834.00
1831.72
1828.61
1828.34
1825.70
1814.09
1813.84
1813.74
1803.58
1802.84
1797.87
1797.30
1795.70
```

I would like to make a ZONE of the above prices where every value closer to each other with difference of <=3.00

sample result:

[image: from excel file]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using the `LEAD()` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN val - LEAD(val) OVER (ORDER BY val DESC) > 3
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS label
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT val, SUM(label) OVER (ORDER BY val DESC) AS zone
    FROM cte
)

SELECT MIN(val) AS min_val, MAX(val) AS max_val, zone
FROM cte2
GROUP BY zone
ORDER BY MAX(val) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. How to apply the above code on this SQL query? SELECT * FROM tblKL WHERE klTF like 'MN1' ORDER BY klPS DESC klTF klPS
MN1 1834.14
MN1 1834
MN1 1831.72
MN1 1828.61
MN1 1828.34
MN1 1825.7
MN1 1814.09
MN1 1813.84
MN1 1813.74
MN1 1803.58
MN1 1802.84
MN1 1797.87
MN1 1797.3
MN1 1795.7

Comment: You should be able to literally cut and paste this code into your SQLite and just run it.